# Android accessing SQLite Database from multiple threads

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite

I have a SQLite Database in android that is accessed from a thread when the activity is running, and in the onPause() of the activity a new thread is created to save everything into the database with a different thread to avoid timeout issues. However, when I try to do so, I either get database is locked errors. How can I fix this? Since I need to access the database from a separate thread in onPause(), could I delete somehow my previous access to it since I wouldn't use it again?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access an SQLite database when it already has a lock on it.

To avoid this, Android gives you [ContentProviders](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) to handle this sort of thing.

You should implement your own ContentProvider to do this kind of thing.

That said, databases can NEVER be assumed to be threadsafe unless you manage the threads yourself.  Avoid using the db like this.  Instead, cache the data (on a stack, perhaps) and request access to the database with a callback when your current transaction is complete.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `SQLite` does not support concurrent access, so you either have to have a dedicated thread to provide access, or you have to obtain a lock to the `SQLite` object instance.